# Appending new element to existing one Jquery & Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some elements to the existing DOM element but failed.

Here is what I tried

Method First

```
$('#b-friend-selector').append('<script type="text/fbml">
   <fb:fbml>
      <fb:request-form
           action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\']?>/"
           target="_top"
           method="POST"
           invite="true"
           type="test"
           align="left"
           content="I am a member of <fb:req-choice url=\'http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxx/requests\' label=\'Accept\' />" >       
           <fb:multi-friend-selector
        showborder="false"
        actiontext="Select your friends and invite them"
        eail_invite="false"
        cols="4"
        max="32"
        import_external_friends="false">
         </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
    </script> '/*It is echoing next contents blindly*/ );
```

It is echoing `);` on my web page.

If I remove `<script>` tag from this string it is showing error in my browser console `unterminated string`.

Also I tried putting this string in single line no js error and still printing `);` on my web page.
Second one with javascript

```
 var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
 script.setAttribute('type',"text/html");
 var fbml=document.createElement('fb:fbml');
 var requestForm=document.createElement('fb:request-form');
 requestForm.setAttribute('action',"http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>");
 requestForm.setAttribute('target',"_top");
 requestForm.setAttribute('method',"post");
 requestForm.setAttribute('invite',"true");
 requestForm.setAttribute('type',"Test");
 requestForm.setAttribute('align',"left");
 requestForm.setAttribute('content',"testmes<fb:req-choice url='http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxx/requests' label='Accept' />");
 var multiSelect=document.createElement('fb:multi-friend-selector');

 requestForm.setAttribute('showborder',"false");
 requestForm.setAttribute('actiontext',"Select your friends and invite them");
 requestForm.setAttribute('email_invite',"false");
 requestForm.setAttribute('cols',"4");
 requestForm.setAttribute('max',"32");
 requestForm.setAttribute('import_external_friends',"false");
 var main= document.getElementById('b-friend-selector');
 main.appendChild( script );        
 script.appendChild( fbml );
 fbml.appendChild( requestForm );
 requestForm.appendChild( multiSelect );
```

Could you suggest an efficient way?

Comment: how does the first method fail? Do you get an error? Does appending a 'hello world' message work?

Comment: In what way did the first attempt fail? Did you inspect the DOM to see if the elements were appended correctly? My guess is the FBML won't be parsed on demand, you have to invoke it, so just appending that script won't cause anything to visually happen.

Comment: Strings cannot extend over multiple lines. And btw, both is JavaScript ;)

Comment: @JohnP I added how it is failing in my question.

Comment: Felix has pointed out your problem. Also, you might want to escape those opening and closing tags of the `<script>` tag

Comment: @Felix and @ JohnP I tried putting everything in single line and ther is no js error it is printing the `);` on web page which is basically the closing brace of `append` function. Please check updated question

Comment: @Shakthi, as I mentioned earlier, you have to escape your script tag as well. it's breaking your string.

Comment: @JohnP: How can I escape it Did you mean `<\/script>`?

Comment: HTML encode them `&lt;/script&gt; `

Comment: @JohnP: But this will print tag directly on browser something like `<script>`

Comment: @shakthi, if you look at your DOM after you append the element, you'll see that the string your appending is malformed. you need to either escape or encode. See which one works

Answer (score 0):

multiline strings should end with \

you may try this one, but probably the problem is from  you should not escape it and if your file is not parsed by php (eg. .js or .html)

```
$('#b-friend-selector').append('<script type="text/fbml"></script>').html(
   '<fb:fbml>\
      <fb:request-form\
           action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\']?>/"\
           target="_top"\
           method="POST"\
           invite="true"\
           type="test"\
           align="left"\
           content="I am a member of <fb:req-choice url=\'http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxx/requests\' label=\'Accept\' />" >       \
           <fb:multi-friend-selector\
        showborder="false"\
        actiontext="Select your friends and invite them"\
        eail_invite="false"\
        cols="4"\
        max="32"\
        import_external_friends="false">\
         </fb:request-form>\
        </fb:fbml>'
    );
```